# Sub-queries in associations with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Anyone knows if is possible to use sub-queries in associations like this query bellow?

```
SELECT l, o
FROM User u
    INNER JOIN u.licenses l
    LEFT JOIN l.orders o 
        WITH o.id = (
            SELECT MAX(lastOrder.id)
            FROM Order lastOrder
            WHERE lastOrder.license = l
        )
WHERE u.idtPerson = :idtPerson
    AND l.statusCode != 3
```

I found this workaround...

```
SELECT l, o
FROM User u
    INNER JOIN u.licenses l
    LEFT JOIN l.orders o
WHERE u.idtPerson = :idtPerson
    AND l.statusCode != 3
    AND (
        o.id IS NULL
        OR o.id = (
            SELECT MAX(lastOrder.id)
            FROM Order lastOrder
            WHERE lastOrder.license = l
        )
    )
```

But I really believe that is not a good solution, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be making the subquery in another query, list it with maxresults=1, and pass it by parameter to the original query.

Something like this:

```
Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery("SELECT MAX(lastOrder.id)
                                      FROM Order lastOrder
                                      WHERE lastOrder.license = l");    
hqlQuery.setMaxResults(1);
List results = hqlQuery.list();
Integer maxId = null;
if (!results.isEmpty()){
   maxId = results.get(0);
}
Query hqlQuery1 = session.createQuery("SELECT l, o
                                       FROM User u
                                       INNER JOIN u.licenses l
                                       LEFT JOIN l.orders o 
                                       WITH o.id = :maxId
                                       WHERE u.idtPerson = :idtPerson
                                       AND l.statusCode != 3");
hqlQuery1.setParameter("maxId", maxId);
hqlQuery1.list();
...etc...
```

Maybe this will work for you